# append values in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I am New to Pandas, and i have a situation in hand where I Have the dataframe
such as below:

and I want to add another column to the dataframe which makes it look like below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RI8E.png)

Can someone kindly help. I have tried my ways to convert it into dictionary and print values but that is not giving me the output in this form.

Comment: You should post at least a small code snippet where you show that you at least tried to do it on your own. Oh and images as data representation is not the recommended way for stackoverflow!

Comment: [Please don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `join`ed values to new column as `string`s:

```
df['col 5'] = (df.groupby(['col 1','col 2','col 3'])['col 4']
                 .transform(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))))
print (df)
  col 1 col 2 col 3  col 4        col 5
0     A     B     C     25  25,22,23,45
1     A     B     C     22  25,22,23,45
2     A     B     C     23  25,22,23,45
3     A     B     C     45  25,22,23,45
4     P     Q     R      9     9,109,20
5     P     Q     R    109     9,109,20
6     P     Q     R     20     9,109,20
```

If need `list`s use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.join(df.groupby(['col 1','col 2','col 3'])['col 4']
               .apply(list).rename('col 5'), on=['col 1','col 2','col 3'])
print (df)
  col 1 col 2 col 3  col 4             col 5
0     A     B     C     25  [25, 22, 23, 45]
1     A     B     C     22  [25, 22, 23, 45]
2     A     B     C     23  [25, 22, 23, 45]
3     A     B     C     45  [25, 22, 23, 45]
4     P     Q     R      9      [9, 109, 20]
5     P     Q     R    109      [9, 109, 20]
6     P     Q     R     20      [9, 109, 20]
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I tried, but got the below error:                                     AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'transfrom'            please note, My purpose is to groupby col1,2 and in Col 4(which is the new column i want to add), I only append the values for col 3 after the group by.

Comment: @sayansen - oops, it was my typo, need `transform`